# Cant run Spring integration test because container doesn't start

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, transitive-dependency

I am trying to understand why my SpringBoot app is not starting from an integration test. I am completely confused, I don't know if it has to do something to do with my dependencies and how to solve it.

This is the test that I am running:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class TicTacToeAcceptaceTest {
//my tests are here...
}
```

The stacktrace says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:190)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.doStart(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 37 more
```

I thought that I maybe had a transitive dependency, but I am not sure how to find it and fix it. This is my gradle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

//applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"]

repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://repo.bodar.com"
        }
}

ext {
    commonsLangVersion = '3.4'
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.19'
    unirestVersion = '1.4.8'
    jsonioVersion = '4.4.0'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    assertjVersion = '3.3.0'
    jsonassertVersion = '1.3.0'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    yatspecVersion = '217'
    seleniumJavaVersion = '2.48.2'
    seleniumVersion = '2.48.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: commonsLangVersion
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
    compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: unirestVersion
    compile group: 'com.cedarsoftware', name: 'json-io', version: jsonioVersion

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name:'assertj-core', version: assertjVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.skyscreamer', name:'jsonassert', version: jsonassertVersion
    testCompile group: 'com.googlecode.yatspec', name:'yatspec', version: yatspecVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name:'selenium-java', version: seleniumVersion
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "2.11"
}
```

Comment: You should mock servlet objects.

Comment: What that means, Why I have to do it and How can I do it?

Comment: Do something, then comeback and tell us the problem. Also if you have another question you can post it on a separate page.

Comment: You're right that it's a transitive dependency that's the problem. Something's pulling in an old (pre-3.0) version of the Servlet API. Can you update your question with the output from `./gradlew dependencies --configuration testRuntime`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a transitive dependency issue. Try adding

```
configurations {
        provided.all*.exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}
```

This should stop any older versions of the library with different method signatures coming through.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today.  My setup had various test classes some including `@WebConfiguration` and `@IntegrationTest` and some only containing `@IntegrationTest`.  All tests were loading same context except some didn't require full server started.
I have not idea why when i added `@WebConfiguration` to the other tests that didnt need it the tests ran fine.  (although a bit slower becasue i had to start a server each time).